# Resizable Splitter View Swift+iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking for a splitter view widget to split my main (iPhone) view into two distinct views: top and bottom; where you can dynamically drag (the splitter divider/bar) and move the splitter position--so when the splitter bar is dragged and one view is enlarged the other view is shrunken. I'd be very grateful for your help.

Thanks,
Helen

Comment: Just thoughts off the top of my head for someone that wants to tackle this....You could probably do this with a ViewController subclass, splitting the VC into two separate `UIView`s.  You could have a viewController to handle data for each, move(`didMove(toParentViewController:)`)  into one of the view's.  You'll need some kind of divider element that the user can drag up and down.  Animating the UIViews' frame change.

Comment: If you present a design/sketch it would be helpful to solve your problem .

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController (note, I have not tried it, but found it by clicking the first link returned by searching google for `Resizable Splitter View Swift+iOS` (the subject of your post)).

Comment: Take a look at the `UIViewController` documentation, in particular the `Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container`. Then, when you have some code, please edit your post with what you have and what you want. That way, more people will be able to help you.

Comment: Checkout SplitView https://github.com/twodayslate/SplitView